# PHP mysqli query returning result "1" on joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to pull out some values from php-mysql, and it's returning a strange result "1". It comprises of an inner join with a where clause, everything works fine, but the result is strangely "1" when I try to `echo` out the ID, but I am assured that the ID is not 1. When I run the same query on the MySQL CLI, it returns exactly what I need but in the php, it doesn't even say there's an error.

Interestingly, only the ID is returning "1", everything else is returning the correct values. The ID on the CLI is- `"V8FBaMJT6bqPbpRutJgkRdc44S3Gz3H8VjW5iu5E4yhBlLA1/D8o+EcGMUY62LZLrxb2SSkaxBoUwaiQXQv+3OsoDTuheYTy4ibPsy91X8JhNGFjOWM2MWQyMWMxMTBmMTU5YjU5NzU2NGM3OTc1YQ=="`, so there's no chance that it is equal to "1".

```
$showPosts = "SELECT * FROM box 
              INNER JOIN interactions 
              ON box.u_id=interactions.actorid 
              WHERE interactions.actorid=? 
                AND interactions.type IN ('1','5') 
              ORDER BY box.time_created";

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($showPosts)) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $b = "V8FBaMJT6bqPbpRutJgkRdc44S3Gz3H8VjW5iu5E4yhBlLA1/D8o+EcGMUY62LZLrxb2SSkaxBoUwaiQXQv+3OsoDTuheYTy4ibPsy91X8JhNGFjOWM2MWQyMWMxMTBmMTU5YjU5NzU2NGM3OTc1YQ==";
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $b);


    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $metaResults = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $fields = $metaResults->fetch_fields();
    $statementParams = '';

    //build the bind_results statement dynamically so I can get the results in an array
    foreach($fields as $field){
        if(empty($statementParams)){
            $statementParams .= "\$post['".$field->name."']";
        } else {
            $statementParams .= ", \$post['".$field->name."']";
        }
    }

    $statment = "\$stmt->bind_result($statementParams);";
    eval($statment);

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $post['id'];
        echo $post['time_created'];
    }
}
```

Now, in the result- the first is the strange "1" and the second is the timestamp.
Also, if I remove the INNER join part, and do a simple `SELECT * FROM box`, it returns the ID perfectly. And I have also tried doing a `stmt->num_rows`, and it returns '0'. Maybe I am missing something obvious.

I am new to using joins in php mysql and it has been a big headache for me for the last 2 hours, any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors?

Comment: Nope, no errors @MatthewHerbst

Comment: Hmm, I feel like you should be. You define `b` after you bind it, so I question if `interactions.actorid` in `$stmt->bind_param("s", $b);` actually has the correct value.

Comment: I have tried after binding it,, didn't work. And that is assured to be the correct value, I have run the same query replaicing the "?" with the value of `$b`, and it returned me what I wanted.

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee why did you define `$b` after you called `$stmt->bind_param("s", $b)`

Comment: Either way, the result is same. And the post was edited to put it there, I didn't do it . It's not working either way. @iismathwizard

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee actually, the first version of this post (in the post history) says that the `$b` was definitely set after `bind_param`.

Comment: @iismathwizard, here you go, corrected it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, as I said, I ran it in the mysql CLI, and it returned the results perfectly. And also, other than the ID, other values are getting returned as well.

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee why are you using eval like that?!?! `$statment = "\$stmt->bind_result($statementParams);";
    eval($statment);` This makes no sense...

Comment: @iismathwizard I got it here-http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#107034, and up until now, it's been working fine for me.

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee Oh i see now. i thought the second `$` was escaped so that statement would be redundant. Even so, there is another way to do this that doesn't require the use of eval. It's just a little more verbose. I guess this is fine for a quick way to do it.

Comment: So, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, I have come to an working example and it works just fine. 
Someone else might face the same problems in the future and make mistakes, so I am posting an answer to the problem here:

---

### Problems:

1. **Having same column names in two joined tables**

The first problem was the the table **interactions** had the same column name `id` as that of the table **box**. Since I used `SELECT * FROM box` along an inner join with **interactions**,  it resulted in the return of the results based on the second `id` which was of **interactions** rather than **box**.

2. **Not storing the results before showing record count**

Secondly, the problem was the results were not being stored as in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php, which was a silly mistake.

---

### Solutions:

- **Addressing the column repition**

So, firstly I decided to change the column name of the table **interactions** for `id`, and I changed it to `inter_id` to avoid further conflicts. Though not a very smart step, it will avoid such silly mistakes in the future.  Then as pointed out by the previous answer, I had to specify the column names of the results I wanted to output rather than using a `SELECT *`, so I changed it to

```
              SELECT box.id, box.time_created FROM box 
              INNER JOIN interactions 
              ON box.u_id=interactions.actorid 
              WHERE interactions.actorid=? 
              AND interactions.type IN ('1','5') 
              ORDER BY box.time_created";
```

That pretty much solved the first problem.

- **Counting the number of results**

The second one was just about adding the `$stmt->store_result();` to the code and it worked flawlessly just before I did a `echo $stmt->num_rows;` and it showed the results perfectly.

Thank you, again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use `SELECT * FROM ...` which returns every column from any table you are using. This is not what you want. **Always** write the columns you want to read from the query.

In this case you have more than one `Id` column in your result set, one from the table `box`, the other one from the table `interactions`. The value of `$post['id']` will contain the value of the `interactions` table. So, change the SELECT query by writing:

```
SELECT box.id, box.time_created FROM ...
```

Also, do not use the `eval()` function, **ever**. You might want to switch to PDO which has a more clear API (the [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) function returns the next row as an array)

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But how do I fix the issue of showing the number of rows? The output is returned as desired but I am still getting 0 when `echo`-ing `$stmt->num_rows;`.

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee You have to call [mysqli_stmt::store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php), as stated on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php.

Comment: Done that as well, I have fixed my problems by myself but thanks anyways. :)